# Mapping values of an array

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

My Array from the Json is as below

```
[
  {Priority: low,
Status: received
Creator: ABC
},
 {Priority: high,
Status: received
Creator: DEF
}
  ]
```

I need to map the values of the Priority field , the priority field has to be mapped to color and the values as below

```
[
  {color: Orange,
Status: received
Creator: ABC
},
 {color: red,
Status: received
Creator: DEF
}

  ]
```

Comment: What is the mapping rule? (which color corresponds which value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lodash or underscore, `Array.prototype.map` can help:

```js
let originArray = [
  {Priority: 'low',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'ABC'
  },
  {Priority: 'high',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'DEF'
  }
];

function getColorFromPriority(priority) {
  if (priority === 'low') {
    return 'yellow';
  } else if (priority === 'high') {
    return 'red';
  }
}

let resultArray = originArray.map(function(o) {
  o.color = getColorFromPriority(o.Priority);
  delete o.Priority;
  return o;
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Does this really give the expected result?

Comment: @chsdk Sorry, I missed the property change from "Priority" to "color". I've edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using only JavaScript you can use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) along with [**Object.keys()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can loop over your array and return another array with custom objects.

This is how would be your code:

```
var filteredResults = data.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(k) {
    if (k !== 'Priority' && item.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      obj[k] = item[k]
    } else if (k === 'Priority' && item.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      if (item[k] === 'low') obj['color'] = 'Orange';
      else if (item[k] === 'high') obj['color'] = 'Red';
    }
  });
  return obj;
});
```

**Demo:**

This is a working Demo snippet:

```js
var data = [{
    Priority: 'low',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'ABC'
  },
  {
    Priority: 'high',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'DEF'
  }
];

var filteredResults = data.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(k) {
    if (k !== "Priority" && item.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      obj[k] = item[k]
    } else if (k === 'Priority') {
      if (item[k] === 'low') obj['color'] = 'Orange';
      else if (item[k] === 'high') obj['color'] = 'Red';
    }
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(filteredResults);
```

---

**Improvement:**

You can see that I used two `if` blocks to test over `Priority` levels here:

```
if (item[k] === 'low') obj['color'] = 'Orange';
else if (item[k] === 'high') obj['color'] = 'Red';
```

If you have more `Priority` levels you better use a custom `object` to store these levels and their respective colors, something like:

```
var levels = {"low" : "Orange", "high": "Red"}
```

And then just use these levels `keys` to get the respective `Color`, like this:

```
obj['color'] = levels[item[k]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array#map` and an object that will store the mapping between the priority and the color

If you need more priorities colors - Add them in the `mappingColors` object, the rest of the code remains the same

```js
const data = [{
    Priority: 'low',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'ABC'
  },
  {
    Priority: 'high',
    Status: 'received',
    Creator: 'DEF'
  }
];

const mappingColors = {
  low: 'orange',
  high: 'red',
}

let finalArray = data.map(d => (d.Color = mappingColors[d.Priority],delete d.Priority, d));
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: Isn't this answer just copying mine? What does it have in addition?

Comment: @chsdk Not really. You do not use an separated Object and your using `map()` + `Object.keys()` (which I do not use)

Comment: I just mentioned this *separated object* solution in my **Improvement** part.

Comment: Ok but your are still using `Object.keys()` and I don't. Is this why you downvoted my answer ?

Comment: I used `Object.keys()` to create a new object which doesn't reference the old array objects for safety coding, to avoid altering original `data` objects in `array.map()`. You can see that your code is altering original data too, if you just write `console.log(data);` at the end of your snippet. I hope you see what I meant.

Comment: @chsdk That's why both answers are **different**.

Comment: Both answers are different! May be you are right about that **but** your solution is wrong as it changes the oroginal `data`, which is **unsafe** here, the whole thing isn't about answers or just answering, if we would post another answer: either it will give a new **working** or **optimised** solution. I hope you don't get me wrong. :)

Comment: @chsdk I totally understand you but in this specific case, OP did not ask to create a new array. Thus changing the original array may not be important for OP. Anyway, OP will see those comments and will have a better idea of the subject :)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers stated, this can be done without Lodash. To add a Lodash (with ES6) option none the less:

```js
let arr = [  {Priority: 'low',Status: 'received', Creator: 'ABC'}, {Priority: 'high',Status: 'received', Creator: 'DEF'}  ];

let colors = new Map([['low', 'Orange'],['high', 'Red']]);
let res= arr.map(o=> _.assign({color:colors.get(o.Priority)},_.omit(o,'Priority')));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```